# SSL on httpd 1.3

Tags: macos, ssl, httpd

I am using an iBook PowerPC OS 10.4 with Apache 1.3.4.

There's a mod_ssl module in the config file. I just can't seem to get it to work.

So far I've enabled the module, added

```
SSLProtocol all
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM
SSLCertificateFile /path/to/file.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/file.key
```

I have also added

```
SSLRequire true
SSLRequireSSL
```

to user dir (site/~username) config file.

However apachectl doesn't ask for password on restart. 
apachectl configtest returns OK.

```
Listen 80 
Listen 443
```

are present in global config.

**The website works normally on port 80.**
ipfw has 443 and 80 ports allowed.

Website works fine on port 80, however
https protocol times out.

I'm trying to eliminate problems, so I am focusing on why doesn't httpd asks for private key passphrase on restart?

Comment: Why do you think it needs a password?

Comment: because the key is protected with a passphrase

Comment: It would help greatly if you added your config file to your question.

Comment: I am focusing on the passphrase-on-start issue, because if I eliminate that, then it's probably a port forwarding issue

Comment: Maybe the private key folder needs 0600 perms? AFAIK, that's an issue with ssh, not SSL.